# Array check element ID with wildcard in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I can check an object ID in a array with

```
if (obj[0].id != "myID")
```

I would like to do the same with a wildcard, so that

```
if (obj[0].id != "myID*")
```

will exclude #myID1, #myID2, #myID3 etc.

**I have to stay inside the if statement** for this check, I can't call an external function.

If it is not possible, I can use obj[0].className instead of .id :

```
if (obj[0].className != "myClass")
```

but every object has several classes in addition of myClass.

jQuery is allowed although I'm not sure it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can definitely use an id attribute selector like this

```
if(!$(obj[0]).is("[id^=myID]"))
```

However, why not assign a class to all those elements instead? That sounds like a much more reasonable approach, allowing

```
if(!$(obj[0]).hasClass("myClass"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery (you've added the tag), why not use the selectors?

```
$('*:not[id^="myID"]')
```

This gets all the elements where the attribute does not start with `myID`. You can use this in your if statement like so:

```
if($(obj[0]).is('[id^="myID"]'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) might be one possible approach:

```
if (obj[0].id.indexOf('myID') !== 0) {
    // ID does not start with 'myID'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check that the first 4 characters are `myID` with `.substring()`:

```
if(obj[0].id.substring(0,4) != 'myId'){  }
```

If you wanted to use jQuery it would be really easy to check the id *or* class:

```
if(!$(obj[0]).is('[id^=myId]')){  }
```

or

```
if(!$(obj[0]).hasClass('myClass')){  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, would have accepted it but Jon was quicker !

Answer (score 1):

You can even use regular expressions:

```
if( !/(myId)/g.test( obj[0].id.indexOf('myID') ) ) {

}
```

I can suggest you this really good playground to test you regexp:

http://lea.verou.me/regexplained/

And this talk:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkluES9Rvak

Regular expression can be very powerful. Maybe your case is not that hard to be managed with other tecniques but you would find regular expressions reeeally useful in the future for other problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I prefer avoiding regex.